# Angular Material - changing contrast color opacity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have defined a custom palette for my Angular + Angular-Material project that sets the contrastDefaultColor to light. The problem is that light is white with .87 opacity - I need this to be 1.00 opacity. How can I explicitly declare the contrastDefaultColor or at least bump up the opacity?

Palette:

```
  const blues = {
      '50': '#45ccff',
      '100': '#2cc5ff',
      '200': '#12beff',
      '300': '#00b4f8',
      '400': '#00a1de',
      '500': '#008fc5',
      '600': '#007cab',
      '700': '#006a92',
      '800': '#005778',
      '900': '#00455f',
      'A100': '#5fd3ff',
      'A200': '#78daff',
      'A400': '#92e1ff',
      'A700': '#003245',
      'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to specify a 'constrastStrongLightColors' property with the values set to all of the colors in the palette.  This ensures that any text with a contrasted background will be "strong" (opacity = 1).

```
  const blues = {
      '50': '#45ccff',
      '100': '#2cc5ff',
      '200': '#12beff',
      '300': '#00b4f8',
      '400': '#00a1de',
      '500': '#008fc5',
      '600': '#ffffff',
      '700': '#006a92',
      '800': '#005778',
      '900': '#00455f',
      'A100': '#5fd3ff',
      'A200': '#78daff',
      'A400': '#92e1ff',
      'A700': '#003245',
      'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
      'contrastStrongLightColors': ['50', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', 'A100', 'A200', 'A400', 'A700']
  };
```